# Numpad Enter as Global Hotkey

Tags: java, global, jna

I want to use Numpad Enter key as Global Hotkey, I have tried JNA(Java Native Hook) and jIntelljType but not able to achive this.
Has anyone tried this or have any clue about it.

thanks & regards